# Adding Turtle to Python on Chromebook

Tags: python, pycharm, python-turtle, chromebook

I am new. Please bear with... I use a Chromebook with Python 3.9.7 and PyCharm on the Linux Beta. Has been working fine for weeks. For a course I have been asked to use Turtle.  PyCharm kicks out an error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/jimmygill27/PycharmProjects/day-16-start/main.py", line 6, in 
from turtle import Turtle
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 107, in 
import tkinter as TK
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

What are the linux commands to get this module? I cannot find any specific reference to this problem?

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get install python3-tk` work?

Comment: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
tried that and received the following error message:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-tk : Depends: python3 (< 3.8) but 3.9.2-3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: this was the error message received

Comment: just doublechecked the version and it is Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep  3 2021, 06:18:44) 
[GCC 10.3.0] on linux

Comment: Can you fix it using `sudo apt -f install`?

Comment: the response to that command was as follows: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 71 not upgraded.

Comment: Should I reinstall python - appears from the error messages that someting is missing.  For reference this is the link I found and followed to install python.  (The Udemy Course I am on only had instruction for windows/mac) https://www.linuxmadesimple.info/2021/01/how-to-install-python-39-on-chromebook.html

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I am guessing that this command (command 4 in the instructions that I followed) does not have everything I need (e.g.turtle): sudo apt install python3 python3-pip build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev -y

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does tkinter seem to be missing or broken? Shouldn't it be part of the standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76105218/why-does-tkinter-seem-to-be-missing-or-broken-shouldnt-it-be-part-of-the-stand)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue - installed PyCharm on a Chromebook but Tkinter was missing when I tried some test code with the *turtle* module.

The command **sudo apt install python3-tk** resolved my issue.

Thanks to @PyxlDavon!